# AE per frame rendering FFMPEG forming to video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, adobe, after-effects

I'm trying to setup an automated per frame rendering system using After Effects and FFMPEG. The idea here is that my slave nodes (running AE), will generate the frames and save them immediately to a Samba share (this way I can team multiple slaves together to tackle the same project file and we aren't writing an 8GB AVI file, then compressing and deleting it when we could just render 300MB of frames and form it).

The database and Samba share are running on FreeBSD. This machine will then take those frames and use FFMPEG to combine them into an MP4 video.

The issue that I'm running into, is that when I render out the After Effects project file directly to an AVI file (one slave, no individual frame rendering), the video length is 1:31. When I render out the exact same project file into individual frames, then run it through FFMPEG to combine and compress them, the output is 1:49.

I have tried a billion different things to make the length of the video the same, but can't seem to make it so :/

aerender.exe -mp -project %PROJECTFILE% -comp %COMPOSITION% -output [########].jpg

^Keep in mind, there may be 99999999 frames, or as little as 1 that needs to be rendered (if we need to re-render a specific section because of an asset change)

ffmpeg -nostdin -i %FRAMELOCATION% -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -an -y outputVideo.mp4

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg assumes a framerate of 25 for image sequences unless specified otherwise.

Comparing your expected duration with obtained duration, looks like the images should be interpreted as 30 fps.

Use

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -framerate 30 -i %FRAMELOCATION% -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -an -y outputVideo.mp4
```

Check your AE comp settings for the actual rate. If it's 29.97, use `-framerate 30000/1001`